# knockout dynamically adding a row in a table

Tags: html, knockout.js

**Problem Description:**

I am using knockout and I have a table. In this table, I have 3 columns. The first column has a drop down list. I want to generate a new row whenever a user chooses a value from a drop down list.

Here's my fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/JPVUk/10/

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead class="mbhead">
    <tr class="mbrow">
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <select class="input-small">
           <option value="">Type</option>
           <option value="">One</option>
           <option value="">Two</option>
           <option value="">Three</option>
           </select>
        </td>
        <td><input class="input-small"/></td>
        <td><input class="input-small"/></td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
  </table>
 <button id="saveButton">save</button>`
```

I want to accomplish this using knockout. Is there a way to accomplish it using knockout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want knockout to add a new row every time the selection in one of your dropdowns is changed.

You can do this by creating a view model with an observable array containing items. You then get your dropdown to insert items into it whenever the selection changes. See the following:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([{comment:'first comment', amount:0}]);
    self.addNewItem = function(){
        self.items.push(new Item('',0));
    };
}

var Item = function(comment, amount) {
    var self = this;
    self.comment = ko.observable(comment);
    self.amount = ko.observable(amount);   
}; 

vm = new ViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

If you then add the following to your table markup:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td>
           <select class="input-small" data-bind="event: { change: $root.addNewItem }">
               <option value="">Type</option>
               <option value="">One</option>
               <option value="">Two</option>
               <option value="">Three</option>
           </select>
        </td>
        <td><input class="input-small" data-bind="value: comment"/></td>
        <td><input class="input-small" data-bind="value: amount"/></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I updated your JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JPVUk/13/)

Comment: that is almost correct, except that I want a new row to be added when a user click on the "current last row" and not any row. Your help so far has been excellent.

Comment: You can do something like this: http://jsbin.com/agasey/2/edit It isn't the prettiest, but it works. You can try and fiddle around with index if you like (or maybe even make it into a binding handler)

Comment: while sending the data how can i sedn the selected dropdown value in this way?